# Getting docker error 400: client error when trying to run QuantConnect's LEAN engine locally on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, quantconnect

I'm simply trying to backtest the starter code provided when creating a new project via the LEAN CLI. When running:

```
lean backtest <myProject>
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: 400 Client Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/containers/create?name=lean_cli_0739587438b94317948c15d649098bea: Bad Request ("invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: 
/tmp/lean-cli-kapzl8hj/config.json")
```

OS:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing Docker, removing and pulling down the Docker image again, as well as uninstalling and re-installing the LEAN CLI.

When I uninstall Docker and re-install, it seems to work until a restart my machine. Then I get the error again.

What I *should* see is a bunch of output with relevant statistics indicating a successful run of the backtesting algorithim.

Even if you're unfamiliar with QuantConnect itself, any help here would be highly appreciated.